# Pop! OS, no output to Line Out only when other audio output devices conntected

Tags: linux, audio, multi-boot, pop-os, audio-output

I've recently set up dual booting on my computer, with Windows 10 and Pop! OS (Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS). I have speakers plugged into my motherboard from the back, and headphones plugged into the case's audio port.

When my headphones are not plugged in, Pop OS outputs audio through my speaker's fine. But when I plug in my headphones, and go into settings to select line out (my speakers), no sound comes out. But it will work fine again if I unplug my headphones.

I've downloaded PulseAudio Volume Control to see if that would work, but it makes no difference.

The bar showing the volume of the output still goes up and down, but no sound comes out.

I'm not terribly experienced with Linux, so I'm not to sure what to try. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, I solved that by following the instruction in this link: [enter link description here](https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/)

- So, in terminal launch alsamixer
- select sound card (F6)
- go to most right in till you find 'Auto-Mut', toggle that to be Disabled.